# PHP regexp - how to extract all occurances of a pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that contains multiple WIKI-type tags.  e.g. `[[TAG:4567]]`.  I need to identify/extract all tags from the string so I can perform substitution later.

For example, for this string:

```
this is a test [[TITLE]] of more test [[LINK:27654]]
```

I want an array of:

```
0: [[TITLE]]
1: [[LINK:27654]]
```

I thought that PHP preg_match might work, but it returns a whole bunch of extra character between the regexp matches.  But I think it only works with one match in the subject string.  This is what I tried:

```
$subject = "this is a test [[TITLE]] of more test [[LINK:27654]]";
preg_match( '/(?<=\[\[)(.*)(?=\]\])/', $subject, $matches );
print_r($matches);
```

But it gives me:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => TITLE]] of more test [[LINK:27654 
    [1] => TITLE]] of more test [[LINK:27654 
)
```

Which isn't what I need.  Is there a simple way to extract the tags?  I'd really like to avoid iterating through the string and extracting manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/802926)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$subject = "this is a test [[TITLE]] of more test [[LINK:27654]]";
preg_match_all('/\[\[.*?\]\]/', $subject, $matches );
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: preg_match_all was the key.  Wish I could mark both as answers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an easier (and also correct) regex to solve this would be

```
/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/
```